# What architecture does my FreeNAS have?

Tags: freenas, architecture

I'd like to upgrade my FreeNAS 8.2.0 (BSD based) and wanted to double check which disk image (32 bit or 64 bit) to download – I'm 90% sure that my hardware (dual core Atom board bought about 2.5 years ago) is 64 bit but I'd really like to confirm what's there right now.

I've tried `dmesg` and `uname -a` but neither gives me a reassuring confirmation of which architecture I have running at the moment!

Is there a way I can check?

Comment: @techie007 FreeNAS is based on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

"uname -a" gives you some information about the kernel image you are running. If you get x86_64 in the output, you are running 64-bit kernel and this means that your CPU is 64-bit capable.

To see information about your CPU, execute:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Sometimes you will get all necessary information straight away from the output, but in other cases some further googling may be necessary.

Comment: Thanks - I think on freenas it's actually sysctl -a, which I found by googling the above on freenas when it didn't work - I found it says "kernel.ident: FREENAS32" - which looks worthy of further investigation. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what BSD puts in here, and also, this is what the processor can support, not necessarily what the kernel is built as.

Answer (score 2):

In FreeNAS 8, the System Information tab in the web-based GUI lists the `FreeNAS Build`, which identifies whether the image is 32-bit or 64-bit.

For example, `*-x86` (32-bit) is shown as:

[image]

And for `*-amd64` (64-bit):

[image]

Comment: mine says this`FreeNAS-8.3.0-RELEASE-p1-x86 (r12825)` - so I guess 32 bit?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. If you look at the [hosted images for that release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freenas/files/FreeNAS-8.3.0/RELEASE-p1/), there are separate folders for 32-bit and 64-bit. The x86 version is compiled for older 32-bit machines (but will also run on 64-bit architectures).

Answer (score 1):

What does `uname -m` say? From my FreeBSD info, it should be either i386/i686 (32 bit) or amd64 (64-bit).

The 'FREENAS32' you found is a kernel/system build config file name. It does not necessarily indicate the bit size (though you hope the FreeNAS folks are consistent with their naming conventions).